# Passing complex .NET data to native (assembly code)

Tags: .net, pinvoke, native, .net-assembly

I have a chunk of code i want to optimize and i'm writing some 64 bit assembly for it, i'm wondering what the "proper way" to pass my data to the native code would be.

As the data is generated on the .net side, allocating it on the asm side is not an option.

While it's not a deal breaker i would rather avoid C++/CLI if there is a direct .NET => Native DLL solution

The data i want to pass is in a format similar to what would be returned by this query:

```
var q = Enumerable.Range(bla)
     .Where(bla)
     .Select(item=>very complex and cpu intensive query and subqueries)
     .Select(item=> new 
     {
        a=item.a,
        b=item.b,
        c=item.c,
        d=item.d,
        e=item.e,
        f=item.f
     }).ToArray();
```

Is there a way to pass this to native code without first copying it? All i've found was a solution with 2 drawbacks:

1) Requires copying the data (and that's no cheap operation considering the ram usage, we're talking over 100 GB of ram, i'd rather not double it!)
2) Requires flattening the data (maybe this could be alleviated with a non Anonymous type and structlayouts?)

Currently what i havelooks like this :

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(bla)
     .Where(bla)
     .Select(item=>very complex and cpu intensive query and subqueries)
     .SelectMany(item=> new int[]
     {
        item.a,
        item.b,
        item.c,
        item.d,
        item.e,
        item.f
     }).ToArray();

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(array[0]) * array.Length;
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(array, 0, ptr, array.Length);
```

Is there a way to get rid of the additional allocation and save a lot of ram? I'd really love to be able to use the actual memory and not a copy both for performance and memory usage reasons.

Porting the rest of the code to assembly is a no go, it's way too complex and while it's cpu intensive it's not the bottleneck.

Comment: You have a jagged array now.  It will be a lot more efficient when you declare a *struct*.  But 100 jiggabytes is entirely too much, that doesn't fit.  In fact, it doesn't fit now, that jagged array cannot have that many elements.  So maybe your requirement is just imagined and not based on any practical consideration.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have a jagged array, it's flattened by the selectmany, it's a flat array, or am i missunderstanding what you're saying?

Answer (score 1):

You can pin the array using [`GCHandle.Alloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx). That is the standard way to avoid copying managed data.

This will require the data to be blittable but if it is not blittable then you have no chance of operating on it from your assembly code in any case.

Comment: What does "blittable" means and how can i ensure that it is? It sounds like it could be the solution if i can just pass the pointer to unmanaged memory without copy

Comment: A web search will answer that question. I could do it for you but I am sure you can manage.

Comment: Sure but it seemed like it should be part of the answer as the data was part of the question so i assumed there was enough context to simplify your answer either to it's blittable (and remove lt from the answer) or it's not (and suggest an alternative) in any case i'll look it up thanks :)

Comment: At some point you have to assume knowledge of certain things.